# Can I somehow look at my WorldTracer delayed luggage record from China?

Tags: luggage, china, lost-luggage

**tl;dr:** I want to check/update information on a delayed piece of luggage, but am facing issues accessing the record on World Tracer.

---

Roughly a week ago, I have travelled from Germany to China. Unfortunately, my checked suitcase was left behind.

My ticket is booked via Hainan Airlines (HU); the flight comprised three legs:

- A domestic EuroWings flight to BER in Germany.
- The Hainan Airlines flight from BER to PEK.
- A domestic Hainan Airlines flight from PEK.

The suitcase was checked through from my original point of departure in Germany to PEK (because checking it through to the destination in China would have made no difference).

When the suitcase was nowhere to be seen on the carousel, I filed a PIR (property irregularity report) right there at PEK's baggage claim based on the luggage number (EW######). In the course of the week since then, after plenty of phone calls and e-mails to the airlines and airports involved, I first learned about my reference number for the delayed baggage (PEKHU#####), and ultimately (by BER's lost&found office), that the suitcase is still in the airport from where I had departed, missing its baggage tag.

Now, all (?) of the involved parties seem to draw much of their information from the international World Tracer portal for luggage issues. It appears there is possibly some communication difficulty and lack of information among some of these involved parties. In theory, it seems I should be able to check the record in World Tracer myself to make sure it at least contains the latest level of knowledge, but I am facing some issues:

- [World Tracer itself](https://mybag.aero/baggage/#/pax) just offers the database and management interface; it appears login with one's reference ID + name is usually supposed to be provided by the individual airlines.
- [Hainan Airlines links](https://www.hainanairlines.com/HUPortal/dyn/portal/DisplayPage?LANGUAGE=DE&COUNTRY_SITE=DE&SITE=CBHZCBHZ&PAGE=BADL) to a World Tracer login page, but when logging in [there](http://www.worldtracer.aero/filedsp/hu.htm), the page just says: *"Your airline is not supporting this service. Please contact the airline's website for further information"* [Alternatively](https://www.hainanairlines.com/HUPortal/dyn/portal/DisplayPage?COUNTRY_SITE=US&SITE=CBHZCBHZ&LANGUAGE=US&PAGE=BADL#:%7E:text=If%20your%20luggage%20does%20not%20arrive%20at%20the,report%20and%20provide%20your%20phone%20number%20and%20address.), they point out a [web form on their site](https://ysxl.hnair.com/self-find/frontend/selfFind/checkedBaggageLost) to "check the status of [my] baggage", but it appears to be useful only for new reports. (And besides, it doesn't work. When submitting the form after completing it, nothing happens.)
- [EuroWings offers](https://mybag.aero/baggage/#/pax/eurowings/de-de/main-menu) a World Tracer login, but on [that page](https://mybag.aero/baggage/#/pax/eurowings/de-de/delayed/manage-bag), entering my reference number and name, then submitting the form, yields zero reaction. I can only surmise some error is occurring, but I only have an Android device here, and Chrome for Android does not have a console, so I have no idea what that error is. Quite possibly, the page fails to load some scripts from a CDN that happens to be unreachable from within China (same as StackExchange sites, which thankfully point this out in an explicit onscreen message and offer a fallback). A friend in Germany could indeed log in here with my reference ID and name, so it *should* work. (Going that way to complete and update the data is, of course, cumbersome for both of us as well as error-prone.)
- I have tried various other airlines' websites that offer World Tracer logins, but they refuse my reference number because it's not a piece of luggage associated with them.

**Is there any alternative access to the record about my suitcase in World Tracer, so I can keep it updated, which is confirmed to work within China, maybe independently of the airline?**

Comment: As a side note, this is why I have an Airtag in my luggage now.

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike If we had any Apple devices (as far as I've read, you need an iPhone to use Airtags?) in our household, this might have sped up some of the initial steps of the investigation, but now that we know where the suitcase is located, it wouldn't be much help, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike To add to my first comment: Then again, having been told that the suitcase will *somehow* be transported to BER now to be handed over to HU, and seeing that they do not have a delivery service in the city of the target airport and thus have us come to the airport to pick it up *somewhere*, tracking it by Airtag might have been benefitial after all ;)